# Проверка цвета перед выполением

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть битмап, при клике на какой-то цвет на нём, я делаю область с этим цветом прозрачной. Но есть некоторые цвета, например (#000000 или RGB(0,0,0)), мне нужно, чтобы при клике на них они не НЕ становились прозрачными. Нужно как-то реализовать функцию, которая смотрит, не является ли цвет #000000. Хотелось бы сделать это без if-else или switch ибо их и так уже дофига в коде.

Цвет получаю так:
`Color backColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);`

Делаю прозрачным так:

```
            CheckClick = !CheckClick;
            if (CheckClick)
            {
                
                  myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColor);
                  myBitmapScale1.MakeTransparent(backColor);
                  MapPicBox.Refresh();
            }
```

Comment: `if(!массив/коллекция.Contains(значение)) меняем;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (backColor.R != 0 || backColor.G != 0 || backColor.B != 0 || backColor.A != 0)
```

Comment: Это работает, но что если мне надо исключать несколько цветов?

Comment: Я не помню, перегружают ли цвета оператор сравнения. Если да, то можно собрать массив или сет.